# Are there any open source software for obtaining and processing data from the Velodyne HDL-32E lidar?

Tags: lidar

Does anybody know if a FOSS package exists? The best I could find are the scripts at [binarymillenium](http://binarymillenium.com/2008/07/velodyne-lidar-sample-data-getting-pcap.html). I was just hoping somebody here knows of a complete package for obtaining and processing the data.

Comment: I am working on the 32E too and having problem of calculating the coordinate. Please let me know if you figure out how to do it. I will appreciate your help very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure of a complete package I'm afraid. Given that it is very specialised you might struggle to find one unfortunately.

However, if you are keen (or know someone that is) you could always try building one...

From the Velodyne HDL 32E user manual Appendix B:

> The HDL-32E outputs two UDP Ethernet packets — a data packet
>   containing laser firing data located on Port 2368 and a positioning
>   packet which contains GPS and positioning data located on Port 8308.
>   The packet at Port 2368 contains a header, a data payload of firing
>   data and status data. Data packets are assembled with the collection
>   of all firing data for twelve laser firing sequences.

In theory this means that to capture data all you need is software listening and capturing data on Ports 2368 and 8308. One solution if you know Python would be [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) - see [this documentation on listening on UDP ports](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/udp.html).

Then you could go on with modification of the script that you'd already seen on [binarymillenium](http://binarymillenium.com/2008/07/velodyne-lidar-sample-data-getting-pcap.html) - and in the Velodyne manual is a diagram that describes the content of the UDP packet which you could hopefully use. From there how you use the data is up to you.

Sorry I can't give you a packaged solution, but hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks :) Was actually able to get the raw data using wireshark and the binarymillenium scripts. Sorry if the question wasn't clearer. It's the georeferencing part that stumped me. I thought it would be a simple coordinate coordinate transformation. Read up some more and I realized that it was a lot harder than that. Needs Kalman filtering and such. x_x  Will wait for additional answers if you don't mind. Thanks for enlightening me on the topic :)

Answer (score 1):

I am doing some work on processing VLP 16 real time data in lab. I just manage to employ the C code to do it, I think the HDL 32E lidar will share great similarity with VLP 16. you can code according to the manual of the sensor, mainly based on the packet structure, the basic procedure will be like:
receive packet + parse packet + store necessary information (may write to file) + feed to algorithm. However, if you are very good at API programming (I am just transferring from matlab to C/C++), due to the veloview is an open source software, you may do some programming such that output the processed data constantly which is the best approach I can think of so far. However, it is not that difficult to code for yourself in C.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with lidar and such, what I can share is that I've done 3d laser scanning in the UK in 2006 with a Leica HDXXX scanner. Point clouds were scanned and with a software viewed and stitched. We also worked with millions of millions of points which CAD can't process. The software we used was Cyclone. http://hds.leica-geosystems.com/en/Leica-Cyclone_6515.htm

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Note that this doesn't really answer the question, which is about a FOSS package. You appear to have posted a link about a commercial package.